# Spring Integration - Adding custom headers in Message

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I am using Spring Integration filter to do a structural validation of the incoming payload and if the validation fails then i want to add some custom headers to the original message.

The filter code is below :

```
@Service("structureValidationFilter")
public class StructureValidationFilter implements MessageSelector {

@Override
public boolean accept(Message<?> message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean status=true;

    if(message.getPayload() instanceof CFKRequestBody) {
        CFKRequestBody body=(CFKRequestBody)message.getPayload();
        if(!body.getInitiatingPartyId().equalsIgnoreCase("BPKV")) {
            message = MutableMessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).
                    setHeader("BPKV_ERROR_CODE", "Ïnvalid Initiating part id").
                    setHeader("HTTP_STATUS", "400").build();

            return false;   
        }

    }
    return status;
}

}
```

But the headers are not populating in the Message.
Not able to see the headers added in the next component.
What am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace a parameter and expect it to be propagated to the next component; Java doesn't work that way; your new message is simply discarded.

Use a service activator instead of a filter and return the new message, or `null` which is a signal to end the flow at that point.

Comment: Used a service activator as an implemention of GenericHandler but got "nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MessageHeaders is immutable" when tried to modify headers.

Comment: Use `MessageBuilder.fromMessage(msg).setHeader(...).setHeader(...).buld();`.

Comment: I did in the end but also the problem was that I was using Object handle(String payload, MessageHeaders headers) instead of Object handle(Message<String> message, MessageHeaders headers) so I was using directly the payload

Comment: Adding an example would certainly improve this response value

Answer (score 0):

Your should wrap your result in Message like this

```
@Override
public Message accept(Message<?> message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean status=true;

    if(message.getPayload() instanceof CFKRequestBody) {
        CFKRequestBody body=(CFKRequestBody)message.getPayload();
        if(!body.getInitiatingPartyId().equalsIgnoreCase("BPKV")) {
            return MutableMessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).                        
                    setHeader("BPKV_ERROR_CODE", "Ïnvalid Initiating part id").
                    setHeader("HTTP_STATUS", "400").
                    build();
        }

    }
    return MutableMessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).build();
}
```

Comment: this is not working as method accept from MessageSelector is only returning boolean